# How can I know the regression logistic's outcome value based on a specific value of the Independent variable

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I would like to know the regression logistic value based on a specific value of the Independent variable, how can I do it?
here is my example data frame:

```
        dat <- read.table(text = " TargetVar  Var1    Var2       Var3
 0        0        0         7
 0        0        1         1
 0        1        0         3
 0        1        1         7
 1        0        0         5
 1        0        1         1
 1        1        0         0
 1        1        1         6
 0        0        0         8
 0        0        1         5
 1        1        1         4
 0        0        1         2
 1        0        0         9
 1        1        1         2  ", header = TRUE)
```

I did a logistic regression:

```
model<-glm( TargetVar ~  Var3 , data = dat, family='binomial')
```

What should I do to get the value of the regression for Var3=6 for example?

Comment: Are you after the coefficient (`coef`) for the Var3 term, or would you like to know the result (`model$fitted`) for the row where var3 is equal to 6?

Comment: Alternatively, you might be interested in predicting to new data, in which case take a look at `?predict`.

Comment: Hi Steph,I would like to know the result for the row where var3 is equal to 6

Comment: Note that `model$fitted` will give you a vector of fitted values that correspond to the values `Var3`, and will be in the same order as that in which `Var3` was provided. In other words, the fitted value when `Var3` is 6 will be the 8th element of that vector (since the value 6 appears 8th in the `Var3` data used to fit the model). The same result can be obtained with `predict(model, newdata=data.frame(Var3=6), type='response')`.